# What is the need to use RVM .gems file in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, gemfile

There is my question: I wonder why using a RVM `.gems` (see http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/initial/ to know what I'm tlaking about) in a Rails app while we use Gemfile to install our gems in our project?

I think that could be useful when deploying a project for the first time and ensure (eg.) `bundler` is installed before running (automatically?) a command like `bundle install` through the `.rvmrc` file.

I am right? Is there any use case I am missing?

In short, I want to know what is the interest of `*.gems` file?

Thanks in advance for all your help that will make me learn a lot ;)

Comment: question needs more clarification, specifically around "I wonder why useing an RVM .gems in a Rails app while we use Gemfile to install our gems in our project"

Comment: In short, I want to know what is the interest of `*.gems` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.gems` and `Gemfile` is rather explicit, You need only one of them, `.gems` file is more useful for small projects or even for your preferred gems, mostly when there is not much dependencies, in contrary `Gemfile` brings strict dependency management ensuring you will always get proper versions of gems (assuming `Gemfile.lock` is also used)

There is good support for generating `.rvmrc` in development version of rvm, it will detect if you have `*.gems` or `Gemfile` and include proper code like `bundle install` in `.rvmrc`:

```
rvm get head
cd /path/to/project
rvm --rvmrc --create --install 1.9.3@project
```

Review the new generated .rvmrc file and remove the parts that are not important for you.

Comment: Great! Thanks! It confirms my mind. I wanted to have some confirmations from any expert :)